# jQuery click one DIV and hide all other DIVS detect

Tags: php, jquery, find, slidedown

I have a ticket system on my site. There are several divs which show the original ticket and then sub hidden divs nested between these divs which show the customer and staff interaction. I want to open one div, and close the others and then if they open the other div this and all other divs close showing the one they clicked open.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    // ****** Click the ticket DIV
    $(".ticket_thread_7").click(function () {

        // Slide the SUB DIVs associated with this ticket
        $(".ticket_threads_7").slideDown("slow");

        // Turn the arrow from DOWN.png to UP.png
        $('.ticket_arrow_7').attr("src", "http://cdn.com/assets/imgs/up.png");

    // ****** If they have click the arrow again    
    }, function () {

        // .. close this ticket
        $(".ticket_threads_7").slideDown("slow");

        // .. also return the image back to normal
        $('.ticket_arrow_7').attr("src", "http://cdn.com/assets/imgs/up.png");

        return false;
    });
});
```

The HTML

```
<div class="ticket_thread_7">
    <p>I want to return my order <img src="http://cdn.com/assets/imgs/up.png" class="ticket_arrow_7"></p>
    <div class="ticket_threads_7" style="display:none">

        <div class="staff_7_1"><p>We cannot accept a return on this item.</p></div>
        <div class="cus_7_2"><p>Why not.</p></div>
        <div class="staff_7_3"><p>Please visit cdn.com/returnterms to see our policy, apologies.</p></div>

    </div>
</div>
```

This current solution works fine. As you can imagine though. This is a dynamic PHP driven site so we have many tickets on the site. I want to know in jQuery can I use a command to get all other DIV Element Ids on the page and hide them.

So can I do something like this:

```
// Hide all other current open threads and reset their arrows
$(".ticket_threads_7*!=7").slideDown("slow");
$('.ticket_arrow_'*!=7).attr("src", "http://cdn.com/assets/imgs/up.png");
```

So when they click the arrow, ALL other threads, will close if open and the arrows will be reset and this one will open.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Class is not designed to point to something unique, you should do something like this :

```
<div class="ticket_thread" id="ticket_thread_7">
   <p>...<img class="arrow" /></p>
   <div class="details">
      ...
   </div>
</div>
```

Then, it will be easy to do what you want :

```
$(".ticket_thread").not(this).find('.details').slideDown("slow");
$(".ticket_thread").not(this).find('.arrow').attr("src", "http://cdn.com/assets/imgs/up.png");
```

Also, please consider using classes and [CSS sprites](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/04/27/the-mystery-of-css-sprites-techniques-tools-and-tutorials/) to design the arrow.

Comment: Or you can [create arrows (among other shapes) with CSS](http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/)!

Answer (score 1):

```
$("[class^=ticket_threads]").click(function () {
   //your code
   $("[class^ticket_threads]").not(this).hide();
   $("[class^ticket_arrow]").not($(this).siblings("[class^=ticket_arrow"))
      .attr('src' ...)
});
```

You can use something like this to select all *but* the current element in the handler.

I'm also not sure why you have the two arguments to `click`.  I'm not sure that that does anything.  Plus they seem to be identical.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a mixture of Parent Elements and also child elements. Below is a solution I have. See the demo and download the code and just modify it around to suit your needs.

***[You can see a demo here.](http://jsfiddle.net/kSzqq/)*** JsFiddle source:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
            <title>Test</title>
            <style type="text/css">
                h1{text-decoration:underline;padding:5px;cursor:pointer}
            </style>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                /*bind all clicks on an 'h1' element to trigger this function*/
                $('h1').click(function() {
                    /*if the element following this one has the class 'parent' and the class 'showMe'*/
                    if($(this).next('.parent').hasClass('showMe')) {
                        /*remove the class 'showMe' from all elements with the class 'parent' or 'child'*/
                        $('.parent, .child').removeClass('showMe').hide();
                    }
                    /*if the element following this one has the class 'parent' and does not have the class 'showMe'*/
                    else {
                        /*remove the class 'showMe' from all elements with the class 'parent' or 'child'*/
                        $('.parent, .child').removeClass('showMe').hide();
                        /*add the class 'showMe' to the element following this one with the class 'parent'*/
                        $(this).next('.parent').addClass('showMe').show();
                    }
                });
                /*bind all clicks on an 'h2' element to trigger this function*/
                $('h2').click(function() {
                    /*if the element following this one has the class 'child' and the class 'showMe'*/
                    if($(this).next('.child').hasClass('showMe')) {
                        /*remove the class 'showMe' from all elements with the class 'child'*/
                        $('.child').removeClass('showMe').hide();
                    }
                    else {
                        /*remove the class 'showMe' from all elements with the class 'child'*/
                        $('.child').removeClass('showMe').hide();
                        /*add the class 'showMe' to the element following this one with the class 'child'*/
                        $(this).next('.child').addClass('showMe').show();
                    }
                });
                /*hide all elements with the class 'parent' or 'child'*/
                $('.parent, .child').hide();
                /*simulate a click on the first 'h1' element and the first 'h2' element within that 'h1' element*/
                $('h1:first, h1:first h2:first').click();
            });
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>Yacht 1</h1>
            <div class="parent">
                <h2>Description 1.1</h2>
                <div class="child">
                    <p>Content 1.1</p>
                    <p>Ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Ullamco laboris nisi quis nostrud exercitation lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Cupidatat non proident, duis aute irure dolor eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                </div>
                <h2>Images</h2>
                <div class="child">
                    <p>Content 1.2 Images here</p>
                    <p>Ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Ullamco laboris nisi quis nostrud exercitation lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Cupidatat non proident, duis aute irure dolor eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                </div>
                <h2>Extras</h2>
                <div class="child">
                    <p>Content 1.3</p>
                    <p>Ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Ullamco laboris nisi quis nostrud exercitation lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Cupidatat non proident, duis aute irure dolor eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <h1>Yacht 2</h1>
            <div class="parent">
                <h2>Description 2.1</h2>
                <div class="child">
                    <p>Content 2.1</p>
                    <p>Sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore. Omnis dolor repellendus. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, iste natus error sit voluptatem ut enim ad minima veniam.</p>
                    <p>Magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Sed quia non numquam eius modi id est laborum et dolorum fuga.</p>
                </div>
                <h2>Images 2.2</h2>
                <div class="child">
                    <p>Images here  2.2</p>
                    <p>Ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Ullamco laboris nisi quis nostrud exercitation lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Cupidatat non proident, duis aute irure dolor eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                </div>
                <h2>Extras 2.3</h2>
                <div class="child">
                    <p>Content 2.3</p>
                    <p>Ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Ullamco laboris nisi quis nostrud exercitation lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Cupidatat non proident, duis aute irure dolor eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>​
```